# How to get indexPath value to the NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I have to get the IndexPath values to the NSMutableArray. I have to do an operation when a particular cell is selected at that time it's IndexPath is stored in NSMutableArray and particular cell height is increasing. When I am pressing again on the that cell at that time particular cell height is decreasing. How can it possible and what type of condition do I have to put?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    selectIndexPathCell = indexPath;
    NSIndexPath *previousSelectedIndexPath = selectIndexPathCell;
    selectIndexPathCell = indexPath;

    if (previousSelectedIndexPath) {             
     [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousSelectedIndexPath]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:selectIndexPathCell]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

     self.selectedRow = sections_main[indexPath.section][@"content"][indexPath.row];
    [tblPeople beginUpdates];

    [tblPeople endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(selectIndexPathCell != nil && [selectIndexPathCell compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame){
        return 80;
           }else{
               return 60.0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Take a global variable ex: Int selectedIndex; and now in didselectrow write this 
-(void)viewDidLoad  
{  
[super viewDidLoad];  
selectedIndex=50; // please assign it as your arraycount+1; which you are using to display on tableview  
}  
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if(selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
 {
   // if this is true you can do decrease your cell height
 selectedIndex=50; // please assign it as your arraycount+1;
 }
 else
 {
  // user can select one row and he can select another row without minimizing the previous one so you need to minimize the previous and increase new one. by using selectedIndex decrease cell height and by using indexPath.row increase height of cell
 selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

 }
[tableview reload];
 }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
{
  return 60;
}
else
{
 return 30;
}

}
```

Comment: what should i write in the heightForRowAtIndexPath ? is there any codition checking or else

Comment: @Ankit what is the issue you are facing now, have you removed arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes

Comment: my cell is still not expanding and shrinking.

Comment: @Ankit answer is updated i have tested it is working please check and let me know

Comment: Hey when i am selecting a new cell than all the cell is expanding ??? how is it possible...

Comment: when you select a cell then all cells are expanding or you want to expand all cells

Comment: i want to expand and shrink multiple cell at a time. what should i do ?

Comment: @Ankit in first click expand all cells and in second click shrink all cells... is this your requirement

Comment: nope. when one cell is already expanded at that time new cell is also be expanded and shrink at a time.

Comment: where can i post answer... can you please ask it as a new question ... or i'll need to send answer in comments ...

Comment: stackover is not allowing me to ask the question.. Please post answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you want criteria based table view cell height. You can manage it by keeping the corresponding cell's `rowIndex` in an `array`, and by using `reloadData` function heights can be managed under `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate, the cells height will be changed according to array values. Have a look at my suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396907/how-to-programmatically-increase-uitableview-cells-height-in-iphone/21398774#21398774).

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** (untested version to give you an idea)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(![arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];  // add if it does not exist
    }
    else
    {
        [arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];  // remove if it exists
    }

    [tableView reloadData];  // reload data so height would adjust in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])    
         return EXTENDED_CELL_HEIGHT;   // Macro : #define EXTENDED_CELL_HEIGHT 230.0f 
    else 
         return NORMAL_CELL_HEIGHT;     // Macro : #define NORMAL_CELL_HEIGHT   100.0f 
}
```

Assuming `arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes` is an `NSMutableArray` to maintain indicies.

Comment: I have to make cell which is expand and shrink when firsttime user will click on the cell at that time cell is expanding and second time user will click on that cell at time cell is shrink. only on particular cell which is selected by user. So, I have to manage it through NSMutableArray. How can i store selected index on NSMutableArray and reload the particular Cell.

Comment: First thing `particular cell` can NOT be reloaded, using delegates(if custom cell) add/remove the index from the NSMutableArray and call `[yourTableView reloadData]` so when the data reloads it tooks correct height. So at start the cell index will not be in array, once user taps the cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will call store value in array if not exists and remove if it exists. hope its clear now.

Comment: array1 = [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] mutableCopy]; now i get the data of particular indexpath ?

Comment: Yes, when [didSelectRowAtIndexPath] clicked..Now what should i do.

Comment: yes i already see that..but how can i get previously selected indexpath ?

Comment: From your question it seems to me that making use of `arrayOfExpandedCellIndexes` will help. once the cell taped again for collapse, pick the index from array and remove it. What will you do if you get previous index ?

Comment: use `containsObject` instead.

Comment: Nope. still not solved. shrink and expand will not work.