# dynamically displaying table cells height with boundRectWIthSize

Tags: ios, uitableview

Right now, I'm using the following code to display my table cell. It is displaying text properly. However, there are some texts which are too long, so I want to display the first 5 lines of the text and then if the user expands the cell, it will display the whole text. I'm stuck because I am not so familiar with the new method in ios 7, boundRectWithSize.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.reviewComments.width,999);
CGSize textRect =[self.reviewComments.text boundingRectWithSize: size options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                     attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:self.reviewComments.font} context: nil].size ;


float height = textRect.height;
self.reviewComments.height = height;
```

I tried:

```
if (height > 150) {
    height = 150;
}
```

But this way just cuts off the text, even after when I expand it.

UPDATE/EDIT:

I want my cell so that it only displays maybe the first 5 lines of the text if it exceeds 5 lines. The entire text will appear if the cell is expanded.

Comment: What's wrong with the first method? What results does it give you?

Comment: self.reviewComments.frame = textRect;

Comment: see my answer .... hope this helps u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396907/how-to-programmatically-increase-uitableview-cells-height-in-iphone/21398263#21398263

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

float height = ceilf(textRect.height);

Comment: sorry, I've implemented this line. It still does the same thing. I don't understand how this sets a limit for the number of lines.