# Easy way to expand a table cell

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to create a function that allows me to segue to another view when I tap a table cell. I can't seem to find a simple way on the Internet or on Stack Overflow that supports Swift 3.

Comment: What language are you using in Xcode?

Comment: I am using Swift 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some links that may help you:

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

[Expand and Collapse tableview cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917030/expand-and-collapse-tableview-cells)

Hopefully this helps you :-)

Comment: Just what I was looking for.