# How to use collapse option to display list of users

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to design and code this in swift(IOS) AND Xcode.If we tap on down button it should display items and vice-versa like this:

[image: like this]

Comment: This question is too broad (and I voted to close it as such).  You need to look at examples of [expanding and collapsing UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917030/expand-and-collapse-tableview-cells).

Answer (score 0):

You need a Collapsable TableView. In order to achieve that, in your TableView you must keep track of which sections are collapsed (contracted) and which of them are expanded. For this you need to maintain a set of indices of sections that are expanded, or a boolean array where the value of each index indicates if the corresponding section is expanded or not. Check for the values at the specific index while assigning height to a certain row. Check this link for more help.

Refer ans by [@Cristik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186659/drop-down-list-in-uitableview-in-ios/34585928#34585928).Refer my previous [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186659/drop-down-list-in-uitableview-in-ios/34585928#34585928) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need expandable table view. Basically, you need to control the open and close of sections of your table view.

[Here](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/) is an good example with working code & animation written in swift 3.0