# Auto expand tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I want to auto expand folder(cell) whenever any note(other cell) focus on folder(cell) ,i am using gesture to move cell and dynamically adding cells inside folder(cell). I want auto expand function only when i hold note on folder for some time. How can i focus cell.

I am using single cell in tableview.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: you can disable selection in tableview and add gesture recognizer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand and Collapse tableview cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917030/expand-and-collapse-tableview-cells)