# Expand and Collapse TableView Cells by Self-Sizing with Constraits

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm want to expand and collapse cells in my table view without `heightForRowAt()`. I want only using Layout Constraints.

I have read [Self-sizing](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) Table View Cells and check the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396907/how-to-programmatically-increase-uitableview-cells-height-in-iphone/45424594#45424594)

And now I have a problem: when I touch my cell in table View it not happening, when i double touch on that, it's working; something just once. i don't understand what happened.

this video what happing: ([link](https://github.com/longvudai01/self-sizing/blob/master/Untitled.mov))

this is [my code](https://github.com/longvudai01/self-sizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you placed the `isExpanded` logic inside the cell itself which may be dequeued and result in wrong values , you need to place it in your model like this , so create an array of Content

```
struct Content {
   var title:String
   var subTitle:String
   var isExpanded:Bool
}
```

//

See full edit [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ca5w3rb63nir1z3/self-sizing-master.rar) ( Sorry not on github & excluded the video asset )

//

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After select the tableview's cell **cell.isExpanded** flag change to **true** but **tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)** this code call your cellforindex mehtod and create new cell. so your logic goes wrong because of reusability of cell.